# Road bike control

Tags: road-bike, hybrid-bike, bike-handling

After riding a hybrid bike for the last few years, I just got a used Cannondale SuperX road bike (CX to be accurate). I expected the change in geometry to be uncomfortable for a while, but what I didn’t expect was the drastic difference in handling. Two major notes so far.

One, it seems to be incredibly agile. And while that should be a good thing, I’ve found it dangerous having been used to my hybrid and driving in shoulders. A tiny movement to dodge a sunken manhole becomes a scramble to get out of the road.

Two, standing is way too unnatural. Feels like the bike is trying to go towards the pedalling leg. Not sure if the light weight has anything to do with it.

My questions are these; 1, will I get used to the road bike with time or is this something I have to consciously work towards? 2, is flipping between the hybrid and road bike a bad idea?

If it means anything, I’m pretty much a casual rider. I just did my first 100km this past summer on the hybrid.

Comment: I think this question although good is actually quite subject to discussion rather than an answer. What seems like riding a raging bull to OP will be perfectly stable to others.

Comment: Where on the bars are you holding?  I wonder if you're holding the tops because they're flat like your other bike, whereas the hoods position is probably better.

Comment: I’ve been mostly in the hoods and yes, it sure did feel more comfortable than the tops. Haven’t been down to the drops though.

Comment: Just as an anecdote, I went from riding my racing bike occasionally to riding my commuter bike (with a pannier on the back) daily. The first time I got back on my racing bike after ~6 months, I could barely control it—and I've had that bike for 20 years! I got back in the groove after a few minutes. You'll find that your new bike needs very little steering input, and you can mostly steer it with your hips, not hands.

Comment: You will get used to it, keep riding 

Comment: There's a slight possibility the headset is damaged.  I once accidentally overtightened my headset creating a sort of flat spot on the bearing, meaning the steering had a slight preference for pointing straight-on and making handling "difficult".

Comment: @DanK Yeah, "you'll get used to it" (which would be my answer to the question!) is really pure speculation and opinion tbh (as I think would be most other possible answers)

Comment: This is a great question, and not so subjective as it may seems: road (and cyclo-cross) bikes are fundamentally different with respect to hybrid bikes (as well as wrt to mtb, cruisers and so on).
There is already a good answer, maybe someone can dig in giving a good introduction to forks rake/offset.

Comment: @EarlGrey you could argue that a Ferrari is different to a Mini but at the end of the day they’re both cars ! Both do the same job but handle differently. The answer to the OP question is keep riding it until your used to the different characteristics. It really doesn’t matter whether it’s a CX, Race or MTB. It’s more down to the user than the equipment in this instance

Comment: @DanK they are both cars, but only thanks to the electronics you can drive a Ferrari like a Mini.

go back to the early 90s, try to drive a Ferrari like you drove your Vauxhall Belmont and I will personally pay your funeral.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your bike is not really a road bike, it is a cyclocross bike (CX, not XC). Although they look similar and use the same type of handlebars, they serve different purposes.

Cyclocross bikes are made for 1-hour races in very twisty off-road courses. They need to be able to make very short turns and do not have to be very stable. They also do not have to be very comfortable for long rides. That is a difference with respect to gravel bikes. They are similar, but often more stable and used for longer rides often on narrower trails or roads.

1. You will get used to the bike better for sure, but the inherent qualities of the bike are permanent. But you will become more confident in controling it.
2. Using multiple types of bikes is a very good idea. A cyclocross bike can be a good universal main bike for many people. However, an endurance road bike made to be more comfortable on longer road rides might serve your personal purposes better.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I was in search of a true road bike but this was the best deal I could find after months. Figured they were similar enough and I can just use it for now. Live and learn I guess. Any idea how much trouble I’m in for longer road rides? Would it be better to keep searching and get a true road before spring or will the CX be manageable?

Comment: @Sam Many people do fine on CX bikes even on longer road rides. They can be great commuter bikes too. It is important to have a bike that fits you. CX vs. road is less important. You may consider changing your stem length or height to get a better fit, that influences the handling too even if not that much. Just ride for some time and see. Be sure to get acquainted  with all the handlebar positions they offer. Most of the time you should ride on the hoods.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll give it a go in the mean time.

Comment: There is not an intrinsic handling difference between a CX bike and a road bike. CX bikes tend to be fast steering, but many road bikes are the same,

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Not intrinsic, but a common one. Even between gravel bikes and CX bikes. That does not mean there there are no gravel bikes that are made with the very same frame and fork as a CX bike. But the distinction is common. There can also be differences in the BB height, but again, nothing is intrinsically given, just common or customary.

Comment: Getting more bikes is always better.

Comment: Switching off between bikes makes that you get and stay used to both (all) bikes. (I know it out of my own experience, if with a different kind of bikes.)

Answer (score 0):

Is the stem very short? I find that a long (15cm) stem is results in quite acceptable, gentle, though not highly and quickly responsive, steering. If I were riding urban downhill, or downhill mountain biking through a forest, I would want a really short stem but if just riding around on a road bike I would prefer a longer stem in any event. The bike comes with a long-enough stem but the previous owner of your used bike may have swapped for a too short (8/7cm or less?) stem for fit related reasons.